# sphal namespace is not configured for this process

Tags: android

#### Problem

I am debugging my app using a physical phone via usb, and I'm getting the following notification in logcat:
`I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /system/lib/hw/gralloc.ranchu.so from the current namespace instead.`

#### Device

Samsung Galaxy S7 running Android Marshmallow.
The only Permission I'm using is `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`

#### Attempts to solve this issue

Searching for `sphal` does not help as there are not any google results. Same for `gralloc.ranch.so`

Answer (score 2):

The answers here are misleading:
It is unclear what your app is your and what your device is (e.g. custom ROM, or not, I'll assume Samsung stock ROM and device), but the reason for your error is that you are most probably using native API which from using some  (or according to the vndk error from Oreo, including master build between the two) that has been restricted by the new linker.
I do see you mentioned Marshmallow, but root cause is the same.

Your app should use different API sets.

Answer (score 1):

I am experimenting the same problem, but on Android things. Solved by the following steps:

1. Install the app
2. Reboot the Phone
3. Restart the app - IT WORKS

Previous the error like

```
"vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process"
```

Now after reboot it don't have this problem.

Comment: Install what app?

Comment: What is the solution to OP's problem?

Comment: This is not a solution if the end-user facing same problem we can't tell them to restart your devices.